# Editing contacts on Galaxy S5

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-5

How do I edit a contact on my Galaxy S5? When I click on the pencil icon for an individual contact it has everything grayed out, so I can't enter anything.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when the contact isn't one you originally typed into your phone, but it instead was synced using an app, such as from an Exchange address list. In this case, you need to either create a copy of the contact on your phone, and edit the copy, or go to the source that the contact was synced from and edit it there.